# Остановить выполнение скрипта,не закрыв консоль

Tags: node.js

У меня есть код

```js
    try{
    let data = fs.readFileSync('config.json', {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        flag: 'r'
    });
    settings = JSON.parse(data);
    if(!settings[value])
    {throw(`Value ${value} invalid!Check config.json`)}
    return settings[value]
    }
    catch(err){Error(err)}
    console.log("test")
```

Вообщем,мне нужно остановить скрипт так,чтобы дальнейший код после throw'а ошибки не выполнялся,но и не исчезала консоль с выводом этой ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем,подошло вот это

```js
        console.log('Press any key to exit');
        process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.on('data', process.exit.bind(process, 0));
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Пауза 5 секунд, можно больше поставить, вместо 5000 другое число

setTimeout(alert("5 seconds"),5000);